# Efficient traversal of directories - python

Tags: python-3.x, file, directory, subdirectory

I need a bit of help with writing an efficient code that goes through a ton of folders in search of files.

The thing is, I have the path of sub-directories.

eg.

```
"./DR1/FAKS0/SA1.WAV"
```

But I need to work from any parent directory. And match this quickly.

eg.

```
"./<random_folder>/<random_folder>/<random_folder>/DR1/FAKS0/SA1.WAV"
```

Here, **DR1,FAKS0** together are a unique key.

How can I do this without wasting too much time searching every single subfolder with a matcher statement.

Comment: You're going to have to walk the tree at least once to find all potential matches - though you only need to walk looking for the first part (`DR1`) before going deeper or continuing to the next. Saying that, if you're repeating the search you can always store a dict or similar that represents a cache of the directories, since walking a dict will be faster than walking the filesystem each time (though caching does risk getting out of date).